# Использует ли .NET WinApi

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Можно ли сказать что .net это обертка над языками с/с++?
Поскольку например внутренно тот же класс File наверно вызывает WinApi функции для создания/удаления и т.д файлов?
Или я не прав?

Интересует именно использует ли .NET внутренно WinApi

Comment: странная логика, по твоему получается, что любая программа вызывающая WinAPI - это обертка над языками с/с++.

Comment: Да, .NET использует WinAPI. Нет, это не обёртка над языками C/C++.

Comment: А в Windows вообще нельзя никак удалить файл иначе, чем через WinAPI. Любая функция удаления является обёрткой над WinAPI или над другими обёртками. То же относится и к другим OS.

Comment: @VladD тут главное - вовремя забыть про Native API :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не так, .Net предоставляет крайне сложную и умную среду исполнения .Net кода, часть базовых компонент .Net в свою очередь взаимодействует с WinAPI библиотеками, которые между прочим не всегда написаны на C/C++